# What is "where" argument for in setuptools.find_packages?

Tags: python, setuptools, packaging

working on a python project, I tried to separate source code and unit tests; here is the project structure:

```
MyProject/
    MANIFEST.in
    README.md
    setup.py
    source/
        __init.py__
        my_project/
            __init.py__
            some_module.py
    test/
        __init.py__
        my_project/
            __init.py__
            test_some_module.py
```

And here is the `setup.py` file:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='my_project',
    packages=find_packages(where='./source'),
    description='My project to be packaged',
    version='1.0.0',
    author='me'
    install_requires=[
        'fastnumbers~=2.0.1',
        'numpy~=1.14.1',
        'pandas~=0.22.0'
    ],
    extras_require={
        'dev': ['check-manifest'],
        'test': [
            'mock',
            'PyHamcrest',
            'pytest',
            'pytest-cov'
        ],
    }
)
```

Then, when I run command `python3 setup.py sdist`, it fails with the following output:

```
running sdist
running egg_info
writing my_project.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing requirements to my_project.egg-info/requires.txt
writing dependency_links to my_project.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to my_project.egg-info/top_level.txt
error: package directory 'my_project' does not exist
```

The resulting `top_level.txt` file looks fine:

```
 my_project
```

but it looks like the `setuptools` is not starting from `source` folder to find modules to be packaged.

1. Do I have to move `setup.py` and `MANIFEST.in` files into `source` folder?
2. But then, what is this `where` argument for in `setuptools.find_packages` function?

Comment: well it looks like the `where` function is defining the package directory, i.e. where `setuptools.find_packages` should be looking

Comment: I think this actually could be solved by adding a `/` after source to indicate that it is a directory?

Comment: @RBalasubramanian: adding a trailing `/` to `'./source/'` has no effect

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You are one step away from a working solution. Add

```
package_dir={
    '': 'source',
},
```

to the `setup()` arguments:

```
setup(
    ...,
    packages=find_packages(where='source'),
    package_dir={
        '': 'source',
    },
    ...
)
```

More info on packages remapping can be found in [Listing whole packages](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-whole-packages) section.

However, it looks like you made the `source` dir to a python package by placing an `__init__.py` in it. Was that intentional? Do you have import statements like

```
import source.my_project
from source.my_project.my_module import stuff
```

or similar, using `source` as package name? Then beware that the imports will fail once you install your built package because `source` is omitted when including sources on build. I see two ways:

1. either remove `source/__init__.py`, use `package_dir` like described above to make `my_project` to the top level package, omit `source` in imports (should you get any errors, just remove `myproject-1.0.0.egg_info` dir and recreate it with `python setup.py egg_info`), or
2. use `source` as top level package: don't use `package_dir`, look for packages in the project root dir (`packages=find_packages()` without explicitly stating `where`).

Comment: Thank you @hoefling! This `package_dir` option solved my issue.
And good catch also about the unnecessary `__init__.py` file!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Funny how a solution to someone else's problems goes a long way to helping others! Thank @hoefling for this tip, it has helped me today.

Comment: @HelenNeely glad to hear that! Should you need more information for the sources remapping on packaging, check out the [Listing whole packages](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-whole-packages) section in the stdlib docs.

Comment: I just found an helpful article about python libraries packaging, and it might help other users: https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/05/25/python-packaging